# Solving DDE of a composition

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

If I have an ODE of the form:
$$
f'(g(t))=h(t),
$$
where $g$ is not necessarily invertible.
Is there a general solution for this type of ODE, if so when can I solve for f(t)?

Comment: This is no **ordinary** differential equation since it combined data from points $t$ and $g(t)$. See delay-differential equations for a more general class.

Comment: You have some hope if $g $ is monotone, in which case the situation looks like a delay equation. If $g $ is non-monotone then you quickly start needing "compatibility conditions" on $h $ (namely that $g (t)=g (s)$ should imply $h (t)=h (s) $).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a well-posed question. Consider the simple case where $g(t) = t^2$ and $h(t) = t$. Set $t=1$, then the equation says $f'(1) = 1$. Now set $t = -1$, then the equation says $f'(1) = -1$. Clearly that does not make sense.

Comment: Ok, then under what conditions do I have a consistent solution?